# Looping over a bidimensional array and extract data to a new one

Tags: javascript, mapreduce

I have a *bidimensional array* like this:

```
const bArray = 
[ [ 'Hello World',
    'Hi everybody',
    'How are you?'
  ],
  [ { text: 'Hola Mundo',
      from: [Object],
      raw: '' },
    { text: 'Hola a todos',
      from: [Object],
      raw: '' },
    { text: 'Cómo estás?',
      from: [Object],
      raw: '' },
  ]
]
```

And I need to get as a result, only one array that should look like this:

```
[
 { en: 'Hello World',
   es: 'Hola Mundo' },

 { en: 'Hi everybody',
   es: 'Hola a todos' },

 { en: 'How are you?',
   es: 'Cómo estás?' },
]
```

This is how I do it:

```
let val1 = bArray[0].map(tuple => tuple);
let val2 = bArray[1].map(tuple => tuple);

let result = val1.reduce((arr, v, i) => arr.concat({"en" : v, "es" : val2[i].text}), []);
```

And now in the `result` variable, I have only one array with the result showed before.

---

**My question?**

Is there any improved way in which I can get the same result but with fewer lines of code? I mean, something like a combination of `map` with `reduce`, `filter` or `concat` in only one or two lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compact a lot into a single line, but that is most times not the best thing to do in both source code quality and execution efficiency.

```js
const bArray = [['Hello World', 'Hi everybody', 'How are you?'], [{ text: 'Hola Mundo', from: [Object],  raw: '' }, { text: 'Hola a todos',   from: [Object], raw: '' }, { text: 'Cómo estás?',  from: [Object],  raw: '' },]];

const resultArray = bArray[0].reduce((arr, item, i) => (arr.push({en : item, es : bArray[1][i].text}), arr), []);
console.log(resultArray);
```

However I would do it as follows.

```js
const bArray = [['Hello World', 'Hi everybody', 'How are you?'], [{ text: 'Hola Mundo', from: [Object],  raw: '' }, { text: 'Hola a todos',   from: [Object], raw: '' }, { text: 'Cómo estás?',  from: [Object],  raw: '' },] ];

const result = [], aArr = bArray[0];
var i = 0;
for (const item of bArray[1]) { result.push({es : item.text, en : aArr[i++]}) }

console.log(result);
```

Which is easier to read and quicker when run.

Expanding it to idiomatic JS style.

```
const result = [];
let i = 0;
for (const en of bArray[0]) { 
    result.push({
        en, 
        es : bArray[1][i++].text
    });
}

// or
const result = [];
let i = 0;
for (const item of bArray[1]) { 
    result.push({
        es : item.text,
        en : bArray[0][i++]
    });
}
```

Comment: In the last example, you need to fix `en : bArray[i++]` to `en : bArray[0][i++]` to get it work.